# Cannot read property of null in Firebase Functions

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm sending out push notifications to users who subscribed to a certain topic in Firebase Messaging. Everything works but after the message gets sent out and I remove the value from `event.data.adminRef` I get this error message in my Firebase Functions logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiverId' of null
at exports.sendNotification.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:24:38)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:35:20
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

Notifcations function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var ref = functions.database.ref('/notificationRequests/{notificationId}')

exports.sendNotification = ref.onWrite(event => {
    var notificationId = event.params.notificationId;
    var notificationRequest = event.data.val();
    console.log(notificationRequest);
    var receiverId = notificationRequest.receiverId;
    var message = notificationRequest.message
    var data = notificationRequest.data

    // The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
    var topic = '/topics/user_' + receiverId;

    // See the "Defining the message payload" section below for details
    // on how to define a message payload.
    var payload = {
      notification: {
       body: message,
       sound: 'default'
      },
      data: { data }
    };

    var options = {
      priority: "high",
      contentAvailable: true
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options)
      .then(function(response) {
       // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
       // contents of response.
       console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
       return event.data.adminRef.remove();
     })
     .catch(function(error) {
       console.log("Error sending message:", error);
     });
});
```

What does it mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove the message data after sending the message, the removal, which is equivalent to writing a null value, triggers your function to run again, this time with null data.  You need to add a check at the top for null data, to short-circuit the second invocation:

```
if (!notificationRequest) {
  return;
}
```

You also need to return the Promise returned by your `sendToTopic().then()` code.  That ensures your cloud function will be kept alive until the asynchronous processing for sending the message and removing the data completes.

```
// return added
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options)
  .then(function(response) {
   // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
   // contents of response.
   console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
   return event.data.adminRef.remove();
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log("Error sending message:", error);
 });
```